# Generate positive only distribution based on array

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, scipy

I have an array of data, for example:

```
[1000,800,700,650,630,500,370,350,310,250,210,180,150,100,80,50,30,20,15,12,10,8,6,3]
```

From this data, I want to generate random numbers that fit the same distribution.

I can generate a random number using code like the following:

```
dist = scipy.stats.gaussian_kde(data)
randomVar = np.floor(dist.resample()[0])
```

This results in random number generation that includes negative numbers, which I believe I can dump fairly easily without changing the overall shape of the rest of the curve (I just generate sufficient resamples that I still have enough for purpose after dumping the negatives).

However, because the original data was positive values only - and heaped up against that boundary, I end up with a kde that is highest a short distance before it gets to zero, but then drops off sharply from there as it approaches zero; and that downward tick in the KDE is preventing me from generating appropriate numbers.

[image: Example picture of downward tick]

I can set the bandwidth lower, in order to get a sharper corner, closer to zero, but then due to the low quantity of the original data it ends up sawtoothing elsewhere. Higher bandwidths unfortunately hide the shape of the curve before they remove the downward tick.

Comment: Since normal distribution has full support on the real line, I'm not sure if there are any direct methods you can use that will avoid negative samples. Did you try using other kernels, based on distributions with non-negative support?

Comment: Any recommendations for kernels to try? - I'm happy to not use normal, so long as it accomplishes the goal of generating arrays of varying size that 'look like' the original data.

Comment: maybe [scipy.stats.rv_histogram](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rv_histogram.html) is what you need.

Comment: Would a bootstrap-like approach work, where you simply sample from the input array with replacement?  E.g. to generate `n` samples, use  `sample = np.random.choice(data, size=n)`

Comment: np.random.choice was what I was using previously ... albeit in a slightly different context; I was looking to improve on it here - but great suggestion. I think rv_histrogram is working, but I will finish double checking on Monday.

Comment: @Stelios - if you want to suggest rv_histogram as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: It's not perfect, as it doesn't seem to extrapolate to larger values, i.e. if I triple the size of the final array, I'd ideally expect to occasionally see values noticeably higher than the source array (where as I'm actually mildly worried that I'm seeing a decrease in the percentage of elements at the top end), but it is a good answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As broadly suggested in the comments by Hilbert's Drinking Problem, the real solution was to find a better distribution that fit the parameters. In my case Chi-Squared, which fit both the shape of the curve, and also the fact that it only took positive values.

However in the comments Stelios made the good suggestion of using scipy.stats.rv_histogram, which I used and was satisfied with for a while. This enabled me to fit a curve to the data exactly, though it had two problems:

- 1) It assumes zero value in the absence of data. I.e. if you set the
  settings to fit too closely to the data, then during gaps in your
  data it will drop to zero rather than interpolate.
- 2) As an extension
  to point 1, it wont extrapolate beyond the seed data's maximum and
  minimum (those data ranges are effectively giant gaps, so everything
  eventually zeroes out).